# How to detect when intervalled observable begin request?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have I snippet, which poll server for the user's payment status. It's doing every 5 seconds, while the status is not became expected.

```js
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: {orderId: string}) => {
    let subscription = interval(5000)
    .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.paymentService.getStatusGuest(params.orderId)),
    )
    .subscribe((order: {status: string, amount?: number, message?: string}) => {
        if(order.status == 'error') {
            this.flashMessageService.set('error', order.message);
        } else {
            this.order = order;
        }

        if(order.status == 2 || order.status == 6 || order.status == -2)
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
});
```

Now, I want to show preloader, when polling is performed. How should I detect interval iteration beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this could be with the `tap()` operator, which can be used to do side-effect:

```js
const subscription = this.activatedRoute.params
  .pipe(
    switchMap((params: {orderId: string}) => interval(5000)),
    tap(() => showPreloader()) // <-- PRELOADER SHOWN HERE
    startWith(0),
    switchMap(() => this.paymentService.getStatusGuest(params.orderId)),
  )
  .subscribe((order: {status: string, amount?: number, message?: string}) => {
      if(order.status == 'error') {
          this.flashMessageService.set('error', order.message);
      } else {
          this.order = order;
      }
      if(order.status == 2 || order.status == 6 || order.status == -2)
      subscription.unsubscribe();
  });
```

Another way of doing it without doing side-effects could be to have two subscriptions on the interval, so something like this:

```js
const intervalBeginning$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
  switchMap((params: {orderId: string}) => interval(5000))
);

const paymentStatusSubscripton = intervalBeginning$.pipe(
  startWith(0),
  switchMap(() => this.paymentService.getStatusGuest(params.orderId)),
)
.subscribe((order: {status: string, amount?: number, message?: string}) => {
    if(order.status == 'error') {
        this.flashMessageService.set('error', order.message);
    } else {
        this.order = order;
    }
    if(order.status == 2 || order.status == 6 || order.status == -2) {
      paymentStatusSubscripton.unsubscribe();
      showPreloaderSubscripton.unsubscribe();
    }
});

const showPreloaderSubscripton = intervalBeginning$.subscribe(() => {
    showPreloader(); // <-- PRELOADER SHOWN HERE
});
```